# Take private class instance as constructor argument

Tags: scala

In a Scala class with an inner class, how can you declare a constructor that takes an instance of that class as an argument?

i.e. this works

```
class Element[T](val v : T, val next : Element[T])

class MyStack[T] private (private val first : Element[T]) {
    def this() = this(null)
    def push(v : T) = new MyStack[T](new Element[T](v,first))
    def pop() = new MyStack[T](first.next)
    def top() = first.v
}
```

this doesn't.

```
class MyStack[T] private (private val first : Element) {
    private class Element(val v : T, val next : Element)
    def this() = this(null)
    def push(v : T) = new MyStack[T](new Element(v,first))
    def pop() = new MyStack[T](first.next)
    def top() = first.v
}
```

Comment: And how exactly do you plan to instantiate that class outside of `MyStack`? The `private` modifier directly contradicts your purpose

Comment: Eh... there is a clearly visible default constructor there.

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry. You should try putting the `Element` in a companion object. But anyway this whole design is full of unjustified unconventional decisions: the `null`, the `Element` overcomplication over the decades old classical "linked list"-approach. I mean why not just have `class MyStack[T](first: T, rest: MyStack[T])` without any redundant `Element` wrapper? This program definitely requires reviewing which I'm sure will result in elimination of the current question.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov I'm not trying to write a linked list. I'm asking if you can make a constructor take arguments of a private inner type. It seems I misunderstood how inner classes work in Scala, but generally I'm really not all that interested in linked lists or stacks.

Answer (score 2):

Since `Element` can not be seen from outside, you should refer to it in context of outer class

```
class MyStack[T] private (first: MyStack[T]#Element) {
  class Element(val v: T, val next: MyStack[T]#Element)
  def this() = this(null)
  def push(v: T) = new MyStack[T](new Element(v, first))
  def pop() = new MyStack[T](first.next)
  def top() = first.v
}
```

Comment: I’m wondering if the OP really means to create an inner class here, as it does not seem to be required at all from his example.

Comment: I am wondering too, but I see no other way to solve this problem.

Comment: Note though that you haven't made that inner class private here.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet It's not required in this example. In fact, the entire Element class is unnecessary. I was just wondering whether or not you could do that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want to do this (you should maybe add some information about that), but it is possible, just not with a private inner class. The parameter itself has to be a call by name and it has to be assigned to a lazy val, so that it only gets evaluated, after the outer instance is ready.

```
class Foo[A](_x: => Foo[A]#Bar) {
  lazy val x = _x
  class Bar
}

scala> lazy val x: Foo[Int] = new Foo[Int](new x.Bar)
x: Foo[Int] = <lazy>

scala> x.x
res8: Foo[Int]#Bar = Foo$Bar@76ba819c
```

Comment: This doesn't guarantee that you can only pass inner instances that point to the outer instance. E.g., after your example, this would also compile: `val y: Foo[Int] = new Foo[Int](new x.Bar)`. Still hard to know what the OP had in mind.